# How to vertically center Material UI component to fill rest of container?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

**Background:**

I'm new to Material UI/Grids and am trying to make a login page. The login page should be split in 2 parts (left side takes 5 column space and right side takes 7 column space). On the right side of the login page, there should be two components (login header and login form). I want the login header to take around 20-30% of the container height and login form should be centered vertically/horizontally within the remaining space (60-70% left of container space).

**What I've done:**

I'm having trouble visualizing where my containers/items are so I included some styling to make it clear. I believe I got most of the functionality down but there are a few bugs.

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-grid-forked-duszk?file=/src/App.js

**What I'm having trouble with:**

1. The right side of the login page doesn't match the height of the left side.
2. The login form is centered but NOT vertically and not using the remaining space of the grid.
3. There's no spacing between the grid items on the right side?

Answer (score 0):

1. The right side of the login page doesn't match the height of the left side.

   On the left side(`<Grid sm={5} item>`) you have set the `style={{ height: "100vh" }}` of `<Grid>` which is inside the `<Box>` due to which height of left side grid container increases.
   So it should be something like-

   ```
   <Grid sm={5} item>
      <Box
          className={classes.sidebar}
          display={{ xs: "none", sm: "block" }}
          style={{ height: "100vh" }}  // set height here
      >
         <Grid>
         </Grid>
      </Box>
   </Grid>
   ```
2. The login form is centered but NOT vertically and not using the remaining space of the grid.

   Set the height of parent to justify-content

   ```
   <Grid
        container
        item
        direction="column"
        alignItems="center"
        justify="center"
        style={{  height: "100vh" }}  // set height here
   >
        <Box className={classes.form}>
          <FormControl>

          </FormControl>
        </Box> 
   </Grid>
   ```
3. I checked the codesandbox seems like you have figured this out

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using Grid of @material-ui/core, makeStyle of @material-ui/styles.

The keys are 2 props of the Grid - jutify and alignItems

The code is below.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Grid, Paper} from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme=>({
  root: {
    height: "100vh",
  },
  right: {
    width: "100%",
  },
  header: {
    height: "30%", 
  },
  body: {
    height: "70%",
  }
}));

export default function LDashboard1(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.root}>
      <Grid item xs={5}>
        <div>
          {/* Left area */}
        </div>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={7} container direction="column" className={classes.right}>
        <Grid item className={classes.header}></Grid>
        <Grid
          item
          container
          direction="row"
          justify="center"
          alignItems="center"
          className={classes.body}
        >
          <Paper >This is test.</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```